# How to include file containing declared gcc wrap functions using autotools?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, autotools, lighttpd

I am  trying to wrap the socket() system call with my own custom __wrap_socket() system call in a wrap.c file in lighttpd (a web server application).

Lighttpd uses auto-tools to build, and I am attempting to build it completely static using musl.

The configure script I pass is as follows:

```
CC="/home/riscv64-linux-musl-cross/bin/riscv64-linux-musl-gcc" CFLAGS="-g -Wl,--wrap=socket -static --static -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc /home/lighttpd/wrap.c" LDFLAGS="-L/musl/lib/ -lcrypt -lc" ./configure --prefix=/lighttpd/install/ --enable-static --without-zlib --without-bzip2 --without-pcre
```

However, due to lighttpd's build script and Makefile generated by autotools, I get the following errors (I have only included some of the many errors):

```
/home/riscv64-linux-musl-cross/bin/riscv64-linux-musl-gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DHAVE_VERSIONSTAMP_H -DLIBRARY_DIR="\"/home/lighttpd/install/lib\"" -DSBIN_DIR="\"/home/lighttpd/install/sbin\"" -I. -I..  -DDEBUG_PROC_OPEN -D_REENTRANT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGE_FILES   -g -Wl,--wrap=socket -static --static -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc /home/lighttpd/wrap.c -Wall -W -Wshadow -pedantic -MT proc_open-proc_open.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/proc_open-proc_open.Tpo -c -o proc_open-proc_open.o `test -f 'proc_open.c' || echo './'`proc_open.c
riscv64-linux-musl-gcc: fatal error: cannot specify ‘-o’ with ‘-c’, ‘-S’ or ‘-E’ with multiple files
```

However, if I do not include the path to the wrap.c file in the CFLAGS argument, I get the following errors:

```
/home/riscv64-linux-musl-cross/bin/../lib/gcc/riscv64-linux-musl/10.2.1/../../../../riscv64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /home/musl/lib//libc.a(if_nametoindex.lo):/home/musl-1.1.23/src/network/if_nametoindex.c:13: more undefined references to `__wrap_socket' follow
```

and

```
/home/riscv64-linux-musl-cross/bin/../lib/gcc/riscv64-linux-musl/10.2.1/../../../../riscv64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /home/lighttpd/src/fdevent.c:491: undefined reference to `__wrap_socket'
```

I have the wrap.c function (__wrap_socket()) in a file wrap.h which I have included in lighttpd's main file (server.c). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of issues here.  Among them:

- **You are using the `CC` variable to sub in a cross compiler**, but that's the wrong way to perform a [cross build](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Cross_002dCompilation) with an Autotools build system.  The right way is to specify the system type for cross compilation is via a [`--host` triplet](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.70/html_node/Specifying-Target-Triplets.html).  It looks like you may want `--host=riscv64-linux-musl` in particular.  As long as the cross tools are in the executable search path, with the expected names, `configure` will then find them -- including the correct *linker* for the toolchain, whose use should reduce the number of flags you need to specify.  `configure` will also behave a bit differently than it does for configuring an ordinary build.
- **You are specifying link flags in your `CFLAGS` variable**, which is for compilation flags.  This might not always cause a problem in practice, but it is a muddle that you should avoid.  `LDFLAGS` is the correct variable for link flags *other than `-l` and maybe `-L` options*, including `-Wl,--wrap=socket`, `-static`, `--static`, `-static-libstdc++`, and `-static-libgcc`, though some of those should not be necessary at all.
- **You have put a source file name into your `CFLAGS`**.  This flat out will not work.  The build system will build each source file to an object file, separately, using the `CFLAGS` where those are C sources.  You are tricking it into trying to compile two sources with each such command, and that conflicts with some of the other flags that the build system chooses.
- **You appear to have a C++ project, but you are specifying C compiler flags (`CFLAGS`) and no C++ compiler flags (`CXXFLAGS`)**.  If there are sources in both languages then you may need both. Do not expect the `CFLAGS` to be used when compiling C++ sources.
- **You are specifying link libraries in `LDFLAGS`**.  This probably won't break your build in itself, but it also will not get you the link behavior you probably expect, because link commands are sensitive to the order of command-line arguments.  You should use `LIBS` for this, instead.

You cannot add a source file to an Autotools build without modifying the autotooling.  If you want to avoid that then my suggestion would be to instead (cross-)build the extra sources into a library, and add that to the link.  I leave building the library to you, but supposing that you build it as `libsocket_wrap.a`, you might then inject it into lighthttpd by configuring something like this:

```
CFLAGS="-g" \
  CXXFLAGS="-g" \
  LDFLAGS="-Wl,--wrap=socket -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc" \
  LIBS="/path/to/libsocket_wrap.a -lcrypt" \
./configure \
  --host=riscv64-linux-musl \
  --prefix=/lighttpd/install \
  --enable-static \
  --disable-shared \
  --without-zlib \
  --without-bzip2 \
  --without-pcre
```

I cannot guarantee that that will work as-is, because much depends on details of your build environment and the specifics of the project you are trying to build.  But it's a much better position to work from than the one presented in the question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed comment. I really appreciate it. However, one thing I am running into is undefined references to __wrap_socket in musl's library files.

For example:


/home/riscv64-linux-musl-cross/bin/../lib/gcc/riscv64-linux-musl/10.2.1/../../../../riscv64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /home/lib/libc.a(if_nametoindex.lo):/home/musl-1.1.23/src/network/if_nametoindex.c:13: more undefined references to `__wrap_socket' follow

Comment: @ballsmahoney, you are getting `socket()` calls inside libc wrapped by your wrapper.  This very likely arises because of linking that library statically, and it would be of great concern to me.  If you want to push on anyway, then you could try adding `-lc` to the front of `LIBS`, before the wrapper library: `LIBS="-lc /path/to/libsocket_wrap.a -lcrypt"`.  There's a chance that you would need to add it a second time at the end, too.

Comment: Alternatively -- and this is speculative -- you could consider instead adding `-Wl,--no-wrap=socket` to the end of `LIBS`, yielding `LIBS="/path/to/libsocket_wrap.a -lcrypt -Wl,--no-wrap=socket"`.  That's hacky, and it might not work at all, but if it did work then I would expect it to fix the problem of the C library's internal uses of `socket()` being wrapped in the first place.