# lighttpd is unable to find mod_index plugin?

Tags: c, plugins, static-linking, lighttpd

I am building lighttpd statically for the risc-v architecture, however when running it (in QEMU) I get the following error:

```
(plugin.c 170) mod_indexfile plugin not found
(server.c 1143) loading plugins finally failed
```

Here is my plugin-static.h source code:

```
PLUGIN_INIT(mod_access)
PLUGIN_INIT(mod_accesslog)
PLUGIN_INIT(mod_alias)
PLUGIN_INIT(mod_auth)
PLUGIN_INIT(mod_authn_file)
PLUGIN_INIT(mod_compress)
PLUGIN_INIT(mod_deflate)
PLUGIN_INIT(mod_dirlisting)
PLUGIN_INIT(mod_evasive)
PLUGIN_INIT(mod_evhost)
PLUGIN_INIT(mod_expire)
PLUGIN_INIT(mod_extforward)
PLUGIN_INIT(mod_fastcgi)
PLUGIN_INIT(mod_flv_streaming)
PLUGIN_INIT(mod_indexfile)
PLUGIN_INIT(mod_proxy)
PLUGIN_INIT(mod_redirect)
PLUGIN_INIT(mod_rewrite)
PLUGIN_INIT(mod_rrdtool)
PLUGIN_INIT(mod_scgi)
PLUGIN_INIT(mod_secdownload)
PLUGIN_INIT(mod_setenv)
PLUGIN_INIT(mod_simple_vhost)
PLUGIN_INIT(mod_ssi)
PLUGIN_INIT(mod_staticfile)
PLUGIN_INIT(mod_status)
PLUGIN_INIT(mod_uploadprogress)
PLUGIN_INIT(mod_userdir)
PLUGIN_INIT(mod_usertrack)
```

And here is my configure script:

```
CC=/home/riscv64-linux-musl-cross/bin/riscv64-linux-musl-gcc 
CFLAGS="-g --static" 
LDFLAGS="-Wl,--wrap=socket -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -L/home/lighttpd/src -L/home/riscv64-linux-musl-cross/riscv64-linux-musl/lib/" 
LIBS="-lcrypt -lc -lwrap" 
LIGHTTPD_STATIC=yes ./configure --host=riscv64-linux-musl --prefix=/home/lighttpd/install --enable-static --disable-shared --without-zlib --disable-ipv6 --without-bzip2 --without-pcre
```

Any help on why this error is occurring would be greatly appreciated. From my understanding, by calling PLUGIN_INIT() this would initialize the plugin for static builds, yet that is not happening in this case.

Comment: This is an extremely poor question.  You have not included basic information such as how you are building.  Nor have you included references to previous related questions, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69444278/how-to-include-file-containing-declared-gcc-wrap-functions-using-autotools  lighttpd has build instructions at https://wiki.lighttpd.net/InstallFromSource  If you are building a static binary, you should include only the modules you need or foresee needing, and almost certainly should not have the long list you posted above.

Comment: Temporarily place a `#error my file included` in plugin-static.h, then try to build.  If things build, then that file is not being included.

Answer (score 1):

If you followed instructions on https://wiki.lighttpd.net/InstallFromSource, then building statically will define `LIGHTTPD_STATIC`.  If `LIGHTTPD_STATIC` is not defined, then `plugin-static.h` will not be included in `src/plugin.c`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I followed the static build instructions from the lighttpd's wiki, however it is not completely static, so I added the "--static" CFLAG and also linked musl's statically built libcrypt and libc libraries. I need lighttpd's executable to be completely static for my purpose, and I have alternatively tried including PLUGIN_INIT(mod_indexfile) inside plugin.c itself (after the #ifdef LIGHTTPD_STATIC). However, I still get this error. Perhaps this is related to using a completely static binary?

Comment: I have also included my configure script, compiler, compiler flags, linker flags and libraries (that are static) in my original question to improve my question.

Comment: Have you tried basic troubleshooting steps like building lighttpd according to the instructions and getting plugin-static.h working, and THEN incrementally making changes to move towards your fully static build?